# Trouble creating a SELECT to make a VIEW

Tags: mysql, join, view

I'm trying to make a VIEW but first I want to have the SELECT correct. I'm working with tables of SugarCRM and can't make it. I tried making it part by part and the firs time I got all the rows but everytime i add an INNER JOIN the rows I get are less and less .

This are my tables

```
hu35p_huespedes_cstm hdata, /*TABLA DE HUESPEDES - GUEST TABLE*/
hu35p_reservas_cstm rdata, /*TABLA DE RESERVAS - RESERVATION TABLE*/
hu35p_visitas_cstm vdata, /*TABLA DE VISITAS - VISIT TABLE*/
lvr_libro_reclamaciones_cstm ldata, /*TABLA DEL LIBRO DE RECLAMACIONES - COMPLAINS TABLE*/
es_encuesta_satisfaccion_cstm edata, /*TABLA DE ENCUESTA DE SATISFACCION - POLL TABLE*/

hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1_c hr, /*RELACIONA RESERVAS CON HUESPEDES - LINKS GUEST WITH RESERVATION*/
hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_visitas_1_c hv, /*RELACIONA HUESPEDES CON VISITAS - LINKS GUEST WITH VISIT*/
hu35p_huespedes_lvr_libro_reclamaciones_1_c hl, /*RELACIONA HUESPEDES CON LIBRO DE RECLAMACION - LINKS GUEST WITH COMPLAINS*/
hu35p_huespedes_es_encuesta_satisfaccion_1_c he, /*RELACIONA HUESPEDES CON ENCUESTA DE SATISFACCION - LINKS GUEST WITH POLL*/
hu35p_reservas_hu35p_visitas_1_c rv /*RELACIONA RESERVAS CON VISITAS - LINKS RESERVATION WITH VISIT*/
```

This is the query I'm trying

```
SELECT 

hdata.numero_documento_c as Numero_Documento, hdata.nombres_c as Nombres, 
hdata.apellido_paterno_c as Apellido_Paterno, hdata.apellido_materno_c as Apellido_Materno,
DATE_FORMAT(rdata.fecha_reserva_c, "%d-%m-%Y") as Fecha_Visita, rdata.numero_habitacion_c as Numero_Habitacion,
ldata.tipo_reclamacion_c as Tipo_Reclamacion,
edata.valor_c as Indice_Satisfacción,
vdata.importetotal_c as Importe_Total_Visita, vdata.importealojamiento_c as Alojamiento, vdata.importebar_c as Bar, vdata.importecomunicaciones_c as Comunicaciones, 
vdata.importeconvenciones_c as Convenciones, vdata.importedeportes_c as Deportes, vdata.importefrigobar_c as Frigobar, vdata.importelavanderia_c as Lavanderia,
vdata.importeninos_c as Ninos, vdata.importerestaurante_c as Restaurante, 
vdata.importetodoincluido_c as Todo_Incluido, vdata.importevarios_c as Varios, vdata.importewellness_c as Wellness

FROM        hu35p_huespedes_cstm hdata 
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1_c hr
ON          hdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  hu35p_reservas_cstm rdata
ON          rdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_reservas_idb
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_lvr_libro_reclamaciones_1_c hl
ON          hdata.id_c = hl.hu35p_huespedes_lvr_libro_reclamaciones_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  lvr_libro_reclamaciones_cstm ldata
ON          ldata.id_c = hl.hu35p_hues9aa7aciones_idb
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_es_encuesta_satisfaccion_1_c he
ON          hdata.id_c = he.hu35p_huespedes_es_encuesta_satisfaccion_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  es_encuesta_satisfaccion_cstm edata
ON          edata.id_c = he.hu35p_huesb4bffaccion_idb
INNER JOIN  hu35p_reservas_hu35p_visitas_1_c rv
ON          rdata.id_c = rv.hu35p_reservas_hu35p_visitas_1hu35p_reservas_ida
INNER JOIN  hu35p_visitas_cstm vdata
ON          vdata.id_c = rv.hu35p_reservas_hu35p_visitas_1hu35p_visitas_idb
```

When I do this

```
SELECT 

hdata.numero_documento_c as Numero_Documento, hdata.nombres_c as Nombres, 
hdata.apellido_paterno_c as Apellido_Paterno, hdata.apellido_materno_c as Apellido_Materno,
DATE_FORMAT(rdata.fecha_reserva_c, "%d-%m-%Y") as Fecha_Visita, rdata.numero_habitacion_c as Numero_Habitacion

FROM        hu35p_huespedes_cstm hdata 
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1_c hr
ON          hdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  hu35p_reservas_cstm rdata
ON          rdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_reservas_idb;
```

I got this (500 ROWS LIMIT)

[image]

But the moment I add more lines to the query (like this):

```
SELECT 

hdata.numero_documento_c as Numero_Documento, hdata.nombres_c as Nombres, 
hdata.apellido_paterno_c as Apellido_Paterno, hdata.apellido_materno_c as Apellido_Materno,
DATE_FORMAT(rdata.fecha_reserva_c, "%d-%m-%Y") as Fecha_Visita, rdata.numero_habitacion_c as Numero_Habitacion,
ldata.tipo_reclamacion_c as Tipo_Reclamacion

FROM        hu35p_huespedes_cstm hdata 
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1_c hr
ON          hdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  hu35p_reservas_cstm rdata
ON          rdata.id_c = hr.hu35p_huespedes_hu35p_reservas_1hu35p_reservas_idb
INNER JOIN  hu35p_huespedes_lvr_libro_reclamaciones_1_c hl
ON          hdata.id_c = hl.hu35p_huespedes_lvr_libro_reclamaciones_1hu35p_huespedes_ida
INNER JOIN  lvr_libro_reclamaciones_cstm ldata
ON          ldata.id_c = hl.hu35p_hues9aa7aciones_idb;
```

it gets wrong and got this (155 rows even with the limit of 500 rows)

[image]

Comment: If that's the case, then your joins don't produce matching rows. If you need them all anyway, replace `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I've tried what you just said and I put 500 rows only and I got 500 rows but a lot of repeated rows and made a SELECT for one of this repeated data thinking there is more than one row but got only 1 row :/

Comment: I recommend that you use only join, and little by little you enter the "inner" until you know which is the table that does not match. The most certain thing is that it does not agree with a table some value, for example one empty

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help either :(

Comment: It is advisable that you check the tables well. Kill Adolfo.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit about creating a view is extraneous. The crux is the results returned from the  `SELECT` statement, either fewer rows or more rows that expected.

Most likely explanation for "missing" rows is that one of the tables does not have rows that match. In that scenario, the JOIN operation will exclude rows that don't have matches. When we want to return unmatched rows, we can use an outer join. An outer join will return rows when there isn't matching row in the outer joined table.

For a guest that has zero rows in the complaint table, then this query

```
SELECT ...
  FROM guest     g
  JOIN visit     v  ON v.guest_id = g.id
  JOIN complaint c  ON c.guest_id = g.id
```

would return zero rows for that guest.

If we want rows returned for a guest that has no rows in the complaint table, we can use an outer join. We specify that by including the `LEFT` keyword. For example:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM guest     g
  JOIN visit     v  ON v.guest_id = g.id
  LEFT
  JOIN complaint c  ON c.guest_id = g.id
```

Note that this query can return "duplicates", e.g. multiple copies of the same visit row if that is matched to more than one complaint row.

For example, a guest with 4 visits that has 2 complaints, that could produce 8 rows. Each complaint wil lbe matched to each visit.

That's how the set operations in SQL work.